# Options for colored rectangular content containers (boxes)

Tags: latex, beamer, a0poster

Today I've decided to learn about writing LaTeX posters. I want to ask if `tcolorbox` is the right place to focus my effort in creating poster sections.

Here's why I'm asking. The first thing I tried was the package `fancybox` and the `shadowbox` environment. As long as I had white background, that looked nice.  However, when I changed the background color of the poster and I came to realize that the background color of a `shadowbox` object is not customizable. In the `a0poster` document class, at least, that was my experience. When I set background in blue

```
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{page_backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.0234375, 0.339844, 0.710938}
\pagecolor{page_backgroundcolor}
```

the background within the `shadowbox` was blue. It seems not possible to adjust background color.

```
\shadowbox{\parbox[c][5cm]{0.98\columnwidth}{%
\begin{center}
Some box content here
\par\end{center}%
}}
\par
```

Then I started looking for alternative box packages.

Staying with `a0poster` examples, I found `tcolorbox`. This has more parameters, seems to be fine in `a0poster` documents. I tested on a `beamer` poster and the results are also GOOD. Downright surprising, actually. It usually seems to me that `beamer` contradicts special-purpose packages.

The `beamer` package has its own block environment, but I find that harder to adjust to taste than `tcolorbox` in a `beamer` document.

I want you to tell me if I'm just having beginners luck. Or should I focus on some other box package. When I needed to do color within tables last year, I found there were quite a few problems in adjusting colors in cells and lines and if I'm going to run into that with `tcolorbox`, you could warn me now.

I also have experimented with `tikzposter` which offers its own very elaborate system for creating boxes, but I'm not pursuing that right now because it appears to be very specialized (not portable) work. Correct?

If `tcolorbox` is the right place to focus, let me know. If not, what should I study.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no clear question, that makes a clear answer hard, but a few comments to the things you mention in the text:

- `tcolorbox` is usually safe to use with beamer
- `\usepackage{color}` is not necessary if you use the beamer document class, it already loads `xcolor`
- Instead of setting the page colour with

  ```
  \pagecolor{page_backgroundcolor}
  ```

  I suggest to use the beamer way of doing this and use

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=page_backgroundcolor}
  ```
- I would stay well away from `tikzposter`, it tempts its users to nest tikzpictures, which should better be avoided. Also it nests tikzpictures itself if innerblocks are used.